# Calculus 2 integral $\int {\frac{2}{x\sqrt{x+1}}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals

Make a substitution to express the integrand as a rational function and then evaluate the integral

$$\int {\frac{2}{x\sqrt{x+1}}}\, dx$$

What is the substitution that I have to make?

Comment: Which bit of the integrand makes it not a rational function?  What substitution could you make to eliminate this bit?  **NB** at this stage don't worry whether or not the integral will be easy after the substitution, just make a substitution to get rid of the. . . whatever.

Comment: I understand that we can x^2 and multiply inside the root (1/sqrt(x^3+x^2)) but I dont get what to do after that...

Comment: That's not an integral substitution, that's just algebra and in this case only makes things worse.

Comment: Because I can't comment yet, is there any reason why the substitution of u = x + 1 can't be made for x in the denominator, and then derive u to obtain du = dx at which point solve for x ( x = u-1) and plug back in? This would yield: (1/(u-1)(u^(1/2))) du

Comment: That would give you  $(u-1)\sqrt u$ in the denominator. Not a rational function. And it really hasn't helped any. By setting $u = \sqrt{x + 1}$, squaring both sides to get $u^2 = x+1$, differentiating both sides: $2u\,du = dx$, so you can replace $dx$ with $2u\,du$, you have all you need for substituting to create a rational function. At any rate, it seems you haven't found my approach particularly helpful.

Comment: Ah. So given the authors constraints, my approach would not be acceptable. I apologize for not being mindful of the OP's initial requirements.

Out of curiosity, would my approach still yield an acceptable answer if the requirement for a rational function was lifted?

Comment: Correct, but also, how does your proposed substitution help? Acceptable answer? No, because you then have to integrate, and how do you think you can do that with your proposed substitution? Eventually, you need to get rid of the sqrt.

Comment: As I stated earlier, I didn't bare the initial requirements in mind  when I posted that. Nonetheless, I'm still the author of my solution and as such I would like to put it to the test under a more lax set of guidelines.

Regardless; once the sqrt(u) is distributed out to (u-1), it should be a matter of simply finding the appropriate anti-derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = \sqrt{x+1}$. Then $u^2 = x+1 \iff x = u^2 - 1$, and $dx = 2u\,du$. That gives you the integral

$$\int \dfrac{2u\,du}{u(u^2 - 1)} = 2\int \dfrac{du}{u^2 - 1}$$

Now we have our rational function. To evaluate, use the trigonometric substitution $u = \sec\theta$, and use the identity $$\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2\theta \iff \sec^2\theta - 1 = \tan^2\theta.$$

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to know that substitution!

Comment: You're welcome! Actually: two substitutions! ;-)

Comment: This type of substitution is known (for just this reason) as a "rationalizing substitution", and its usefulness is not limited to _square_-roots...

Comment: Note that you don't need the trig substitution to solve this either; _partial fractions_ works just fine (and arguably better) here.  Since $u^2-1=(u-1)(u+1)$, look at $\dfrac{a}{u-1}+\dfrac{b}{u+1}$; multiply the 'a' term by $\frac{u+1}{u+1}$, and the 'b' term by $\frac{u-1}{u-1}$, then combine the terms and see how you can set $a$ and $b$ to get $\frac2{u^2-1}$ as the result.  Once you've figured out how to write $\frac2{u^2-1} = \frac{a}{u-1}+\frac{b}{u+1}$ this way, you can integrate both of those in the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

Your aim should be to get rid of the square root.

Warning: Spoiler below. :)

> Try $u=\sqrt{x+1}$ so that $u^2-1=x$
> Then $du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\,dx = \frac{1}{2u}\,dx$ thus $2u\,du=dx$.